# Send data to putty in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have powershell script that open putty.exe in process and i want to send data to this process, how can i do that???
PLEASE HELP!

The process:

```
$solExe = [diagnostics.process]::start("putty.exe", "-raw -P 2000 127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: What kind of data so you want to send, what is your end goal ? and what have you tried.You example above is just showing that you want to connect to a server on port 2000 on you local PC and doesnt give any more information

Answer (score 4):

The command line interface for putty is plink.exe.  You can use plink to send commands over ssh.

For example:
PS C:> c:\progra~2\putty\plink.exe -i C:\credentials\mykeyfile.ppk root@myserver.com "ls";

Things to remember:

The first time you connect to a server, you'll have to add it to your registry, so this won't work in a non-interactive mode for brand new servers.  [There isn't a way to disable this](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-hostkeys).

The key file has to be in ppk format for plink.exe to recognize it.  If yours is in pem format, use puttygen.exe to create a ppk file.

The path to the key file cannot contain any spaces, or the command above won't work.

If you want to send multiple commands at once, write them to a file and use the -m switch with plink.exe.

If you need to transfer files, you can use pscp.exe in a similar fashion.